# How two microservices can communicate when they are hosted on same machine vs distributed?

Tags: microservices

I am new to microservices.How can I communicate between my microservices? I have four microservices and parent pom.xml has dependencies for all microservices. Now, as they are not hosted on different machines, I no need to call rest api to communicate. how communication happens between these services? I am little confused how microservices are designed different modules on same machine? or differnt machines as separate projects and then call via rest apis?

Comment: if you are building,packaging and deploying one thing then I would say there is only one service. The idea of microservices is totally different then what you picture in your mind.You may get some idea from here https://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The microservice design is deployment agnostic. They are not supposed to know about each other's deployment. They can be deployed together or separately. They communicate via REST/SOAP, AMQP, Common resource (like file, DB), etc.

So in your case it you need to pick one of the standard ways of communication.